# extra line in google map polygon

Tags: android, google-maps, line, polygon

In the following screenshot i'm drawing a polygon by clicking the google maps.
Using the setOnMapClickListener the lat lng of the clicked points (1-10 shown in image) is stored to a array list then using the method polygon as shown the polygon is drawn.

The points are clicked in the sequence as shown in the image, but I'm getting an extra line between 8 and 10.
how can i get the polygon for the exact points clicked on map.

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                    polygon_list.add(latLng);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.dot)).anchor(0.5f, 0.5f));
                }
            }
        });

public void polygon() {
        PolygonOptions opts = new PolygonOptions();
        for (LatLng location : polygon_list) {
            opts.add(location);
            poly_shape = mMap.addPolygon(opts.strokeColor(Color.RED).fillColor(Color.BLUE));
        }
    }
```

[image: Map Screenshot]]

Comment: can you println the value of `polygon_list`?

Comment: You could try calling `poly_shape.setMap(null)` before the `for`-loop in `polygon()` to clear the existing polygon, not sure if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of suggestions that you can try.

1. Clear `polygon_list` before adding the click listener.
2. Create `poly_shape` once, outside the for loop.

At the moment you add a point to `PolygonOptions` and create a new polygon each time inside the for loop. This may be the reason for the extra line between 8 and 10.

The updated code will look like

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                    polygon_list.add(latLng);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.dot)).anchor(0.5f, 0.5f));
                }
            }
        });

public void polygon() {
        PolygonOptions opts = new PolygonOptions();
        for (LatLng location : polygon_list) {
            opts.add(location);
        }
       poly_shape = mMap.addPolygon(opts.strokeColor(Color.RED).fillColor(Color.BLUE));
    }
```